# How to solve Windows Disk Management showing duplicate drives?

Tags: windows, partitioning, disk-management

For some reason diskmgmt.msc is showing "repeated drives" (click image for full view):

[image]

As can be seen, `RECOVERY (D:)` has two rows, one stating "File System" as NTFS and the other showing blank.

**This doesn't seem right at all.** Iirc, there used to be only one row.

Why is this happening?

How can this problem be solved?

---

• [Many threads on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=why%20is%20disk%20management%20showing%20duplicate%20drives), but no answer (as usual). From the threads, seems to be a HP problem?

• System: Windows 8.1 Core.

• Screenshots of other partition tools: 

    • EaseUS Partition Master 10.8 Free Edition - Free For Home Users [[img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8smRZ.png)].

    • MiniTool Partition Wizard Free 9.1 - Free For Home Users [[img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uaNx.png)].

    • Paragon Partition Manager 14 Free [[img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfXJl.png)].